# Convert string to variables

Tags: php

How to convert this

```
$myvar = '[aaa](11,22,33,44,55)[bbb](1,2,3,4,5)';
```

into that

```
$arr_name[1] = 'aaa';
$arr_val[1] = '11,22,33,44,55';

$arr_name[2] = 'bbb';
$arr_val[2] = '1,2,3,4,5';
```

What functions should I use for it ?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: manually as this doesn't seem like a recognised format

Comment: @Matt you have been tired of being writing What have you tried? :)

Comment: @arpit yeah, it gets tiring, but my fingers are nimble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/',$myvar,$matches)) {
    foreach($matches[0] as $k=>$v) {
        $arr_name[$k] = $matches[1][$k];
        $arr_val[$k] = $matches[2][$k];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using regular expressions to extract your keys & variables, then insert them into an array:

```
$keys = array();
preg_match_all("/\[.+\]/", $myvar, $keys);

$values = array();
preg_match_all("/\(.+\)/", $myvar, $values);

$numKeys = count($keys);
$numVals = count($values);

$result = array();
foreach ($i = 0; $i < $numKeys; $i++) {
    if ($i < $numVals) {
        $result[trim($keys[$i], "[]")] = trim($values[$i], "()");
    }
}
```